# How do you create an SQL trigger that contains logic from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a messaging application and I'm trying my first trigger.  What I would like to do is on an insert check against a database view to see if the user has exceeded their quota.  If they have insert a message into the messaging table to notify the user.

```
USE [PhoneMessaging]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON [dbo].[Messages]
FOR INSERT
AS

declare @uid smallint;
    declare @Message nvarchar(1000);
    declare @MessageFrom smallint;
    declare @vdate date;
    declare @priority smallint;
    declare @MessageLimit smallint;

    select @uid=i.MessageTo from inserted i;    

    set @Message='You have reached your storage limit.';
    set @vdate = CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),111);
    set @MessageFrom = 0
    set @priority = 3

    set @MessageLimit = (SELECT dbo.vUserMessageTotals.MessageLimit from dbo.vUserMessageTotals WHERE uid = @uid)

    /*IF (SELECT dbo.vUserMessageTotals.MessageReceivedTotal from dbo.vUserMessageTotals) >= @MessageLimit*/

    insert into Messages
           (MessageTo,[Message],vDate,MessageFrom) 
    values(@uid,@Message,@vdate,@MessageFrom)

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
```

Comment: I think that application code is a more appropriate place to handle this logic than an sql trigger.

Comment: Your trigger (assuming it's for **SQL Server**) is badly flawed in that you seem to expect this to be called on a **per row** basis - this is ***NOT*** the case in SQL Server! Your trigger will fire once per statement, and the `Inserted` table might contain 10, 20, 100 rows! So which of those rows are you selecting in your `select @uid=i.MessageTo from inserted i;` statement?? This will **not work reliably** in anything but the most simplistic cases....

Comment: I have added the `SQL-Server` tag since your variable names (`@name`) are only valid there.

Comment: Actually, a *Stored Procedure* is probably the best place for this. Triggers should only be used when there are no other good choices.

Comment: ok thanks for your comments guess I mis understood what a trigger could be used for.  I have gone for application code inside my web app